# What Means Fuel Shut Off?

Tags: ford, rpm

What does fuel shutoff means?

I searched it up before, but the answer is not what I'm looking for.

For example: The Ford Lighting's fuel shut off is at 5,400 RPM.

Comment: I hope that is an example pulled out of thin air, because I'd think there would be some ticked off Lightning owners out there if their supercharged giddy-up only revved to 4,400 rpm. I would suspect since it's supposed to be a Cobra engine crossover, it should rev to around 7,000 rpm, give or take ...

Comment: The Ford Lighting's Max RPM Limit Is Over 5,000, @Paulster2

Comment: Yup ... [just looked it up](http://www.fordlightning.com/statistics.htm). Appears the redline is 5250rpm with the fuel shut off at 5400rpm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just another word for Rev limiter. It means that when you reach 4,400 RPM, the ECU starts to limit the amount of injected fuel and air, in order not to let the engine rev any further, because revving it any further may cause severe damage to it.